# How to use both nz-zorro libraries for large screen and for mobile in the same application?

Tags: ng-zorro-antd, ng-zorro-mobile

NZ Zorro has 2 nice layout angular libraries, the [large screen](https://ng.ant.design/docs/introduce/en) and the [mobile](https://ng.mobile.ant.design/#/docs/introduce/en) versions. Do I need to create 2 applications, one for large screen and the other for mobiles? Is there a way to use both libraries in the same angular application?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never do two codebases. You should follow responsive patterns.
You need to render content based on the use case.

One very handy library in angular is https://github.com/angular/flex-layout.
It has conditional directives example :

[image]

You can hide/show divs based on if you are on mobile(xs).